# Passing a stream only if digest passes

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I've got a pipeline in an express.js module in which I take a file, decrypt it, pass it through a digest to ensure it is valid, and then want to return it as the response if the digest passes.  The code looks something like this:

```
function GetFile(req,res) {
    ...
    }).then(() => {
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            digester = digestStream("md5", "hex", function(md5,len) {
                // compare md5 and length against expected values
                // what do i do if they don't match?
                resolve()
            }
        }
        infile.pipe(decrypter).pipe(digester).pipe(res)
        return p1
    }).then(() => {
    ...
}
```

The problem is, once I pipe the output to `res`, it pipes it whether or not the digest passes.  But if I don't pipe the output of the digester to anything, then nothing happens - I guess there isn't pressure from the right end to move the data through.

I could simply run the decryption pipeline twice, and in fact this was what was previously done, but I'm trying to speed things up so everything only happens once.  One idea I had was to pipe the digester output to a buffer, and if the digest matches, then send the buffer to `res`.   This will require memory proportional to the size of the file, which isn't horrible in most cases.  However, I couldn't find much on how to `.pipe()` directly to a buffer.  The closest thing I could find was the [bl](https://github.com/rvagg/bl) module, however in the section in which it demonstrates piping to a function which collects the data, there is this caveat mentioned:

> Note that when you use the callback method like this, the resulting
>   data parameter is a concatenation of all Buffer objects in the list.
>   If you want to avoid the overhead of this concatenation (in cases of
>   extreme performance consciousness), then avoid the callback method and
>   just listen to 'end' instead, like a standard Stream.

I'm not familiar enough with `bl` to understand what this really means with regards to how efficient this is.  Specifically, I don't understand why it is talking about concatenating buffer objects - why is there more than one buffer object that must be concatenated, for example?).  I'm not sure how I can follow its advice and still have a simple pipe either.

Answer (score 0):

The `bl` module is going to collect buffers when it is piped to.  How many buffers depends on what the input stream does.  If you don't want to concatenate them together, store them in the BufferList, and if the hash passes, then pipe the BufferList to your output.

Something like this works for me:

```
function GetFile(req,res) {
    ...
    var bl
    }).then(() => {
        var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            digester = digestStream("md5", "hex", function(md5,len) {
                if (md5 != expectedmd5) throw "bad md5"
                if (len != expectedlen) throw "bad length"
                resolve()
            }
        }
        bl = new BufferList()
        infile.pipe(decrypter).pipe(digester).pipe(bl)
        return p1
    }).then(() => {
        bl.pipe(res)
    ...
}
```